# how to programmatically return to Vue cli's pre-made Home.vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue CLI 3 and it makes a few routes. One is Home.vue. In my program I am trying to programmaticaly go to different pages. I added the routes I need in router.js but kept the already created routes for Home.vue and About.vue. It works fine until I get to 'Home' and get a warning: [vue-router] Route with name 'Home' does not exist.'

Here is the code:

```
 <template>
    <div class='secondItem'>
         <h4 v-for="item in menuItems" 
    @click="bindMe(item)" v-bind:class="{'active':(item === current)}">{{item}}</h4>
    </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
            name: 'Header',
            data() {
                return {
                    current: '',
                    menuItems: ['Home', 'About', 'Portfolio', 'Contact'],
                }
            },
            methods: {
                bindMe(item) {
                    this.current = item;
                    this.$router.push({
                            path: item
                        })
                }

            }
        }
    <script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [named routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html)? In that case you need to use `name` instead of `path`:

```
this.$router.push({
  name: item
})
```

Also, your example can be simplified quite a lot. Try this:

```
<template>
  <div class="secondItem">
    <router-link :to="{ name: item }" tag="h4" active-class="active" v-for="item in menuItems" v-bind:key="item">{{item}}</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Header',
    data() {
      return {
        menuItems: ['Home', 'About', 'Portfolio', 'Contact']
      }
    }
  }
<script>
```

Comment: I had tried that and it didn't work then I tried it again after your answer and this time I checked the value and changed it all to lowercase 'home' and it worked. Silly me :>)

Comment: Yes, names are case-sensitive. You could just use `item.toLowerCase()` in your `:to`-attribute.